# Connect to windows network share through 2 routers

Tags: windows-7, networking, router, network-shares, wireless-router

I have an android device (in my house, downstairs) that can connect to my Windows 7 share without problems through the Wifi signal of my router upstairs. Problem is, that is a pretty weak signal. I have a better reception of my Wifi signal of the router downstairs, obviously. The problem is, then my android device cannot find my Windows 7 share. Most likely due to the fact that my Windows 7 pc is connected (wired) to the Wifi router upstairs. The Wifi router upstairs is connected to the Wifi router downstairs (also wired). What do I do so I can access the share through the downstairs router?

I'm no network expert obviously. I tried forwarding ports 137-139 & 445 in my router upstairs and entered the IP of my Windows 7 pc. Did the same from my Wifi router downstairs to my Wifi router upstairs but I figured I had no idea what I'm doing :-) Don't even know if port forwarding is the way to go or if I should have forwarded the ports the other way around. So, please, tell me, what do I do? Thanks!

Comment: Do you need two seperate networks? If not, I recommend merging them by setting the second router up as a simple switch or bridge.

Comment: Hmm would I lose Wifi? Because I do need that to get signal upstairs for other devices.

Comment: Probably not, but that may depend on a lot of details about your configuration. In any case, you can simply plug the cable on the WAN port of the second router in one of the LAN ports. If you're lucky, it'll work straight up from there.